# Hiding a custom web part in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2007

I'm attempting to completely hide a custom web part I'm writing under specific circumstances.  What I'm not finding a lot of help on is actually hiding the complete web part.  Using:

```
this.Hide = true;
```

will hide the content of the web part, but it appears to leave the Chrome behind.  I can't change the Chrome display, so that's not an option right now.  Is there a more complete way to hide the complete web part using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not worried about the web part being rendered or not, just having it not visually display.  What I ended up doing is changing the chrome through code if my specific situation arises.

```
this.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
this.Hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to ensure nothing is rendered to the page is to close the web part. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.hidden.aspx):

> A WebPart control that is hidden
>   remains in its zone, is actually
>   rendered on its page, and participates
>   in page life cycle phases such as the
>   PreRender phase, even though it is not
>   visible in a browser. This is
>   different from WebPart controls that
>   are closed, because closed controls
>   are not even rendered on a page...

Use the SPLimitedWebPartManager and its [CloseWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.closewebpart.aspx) method to do this. (Be careful about disposing of SPLimitedWebPartManager as well as its Web property correctly.)

Alternatively, use a CSS or jQuery approach. The web part will still be rendered but you will be able to hide it as you originally wanted.